# Infinispan configuration issues

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to setup a cache cluster using infinispan, in replication mode.
And, i would like to access the cache on any of these 2 laptops from a 3rd computer. 
(All 3 computers are on same network).

I have a stand alone java program on my 3rd computer

```
RemoteCacheManager rm = new RemoteCacheManager("localhost:11222");
rm.start();
RemoteCache<Object, Object> cache = rm.getCache("namedCache2");
Object val = cache.get("key");
```

I have configured namedCache2 on Laptop-1, prior to the execution of this method.

But, when i do rm.getCache("namedCache2"), i am getting this exception saying, namedCache2 is not configured.

Can someone please let me know what went wrong?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look right: if you're really creating the RemoteCacheManager on the 3rd machine with `new RemoteCacheManager("localhost:11222")`, then you're accessing the hotrod server on that mathine.

Comment: Right.. i corrected it later on.. and provided valid IP Address. I Am still not sure whether the port number provided by me is right?

Comment: It is right, assuming that the server is configured with the default port too. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/OgY5 and https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/NgY5